# How to place field label on top of field instead of left side in Grails

Tags: css, grails, grails-2.4

I am using Grails 2.4.2. I want to use Grails default CSS with a few modifications. Now I need to place the field label on top of the field instead of left side.

Here are my form element where I want to show 4 field in a row:

```
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'fullName', 'error')} required">
    <label for="fullName">
        <g:message code="users.fullName.label" default="Full Name"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:textField name="fullName" required="" value="${usersInstance?.fullName}"/>

    <label for="email">
        <g:message code="users.email.label" default="Email"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:field type="email" name="email" required="" value="${usersInstance?.email}"/>

</div>
```

And output for above code is as below:

[image]

Now I want to add 4 fields in a row and the label of all field will be on top.

Single field in each line:

[image]

Form element:

```
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'username', 'error')} required">
    <label for="username">
        <g:message code="users.username.label" default="Username"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:textField name="username" required="" value="${usersInstance?.username}"/>

</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'password', 'error')} required">
    <label for="password">
        <g:message code="users.password.label" default="Password"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:textField name="password" required="" value="${usersInstance?.password}"/>

</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'fullName', 'error')} required">
    <label for="fullName">
        <g:message code="users.fullName.label" default="Full Name"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:textField name="fullName" required="" value="${usersInstance?.fullName}"/>

</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'email', 'error')} required">
    <label for="email">
        <g:message code="users.email.label" default="Email"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:field type="email" name="email" required="" value="${usersInstance?.email}"/>

</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'phone', 'error')} required">
    <label for="phone">
        <g:message code="users.phone.label" default="Phone"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:textField name="phone" required="" value="${usersInstance?.phone}"/>

</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'fax', 'error')} required">
    <label for="fax">
        <g:message code="users.fax.label" default="Fax"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:textField name="fax" required="" value="${usersInstance?.fax}"/>

</div>

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usersInstance, field: 'address', 'error')} required">
    <label for="address">
        <g:message code="users.address.label" default="Address"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:textField name="address" required="" value="${usersInstance?.address}"/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Just define the following CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fieldcontain label, .fieldcontain .property-label {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%
}

.fieldcontain input {
    width: 100%;
}

.fieldcontain {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left
}

.row:before, .row:after {
     display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```

And your HTML should look like this:

```
<fieldset class="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fieldcontain  required">
            <label for="firstName">
                First Name
                <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" required="" value="" id="firstName">
        </div>

        <div class="fieldcontain  required">
            <label for="lastName">
                Last Name
                <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" required="" value="" id="lastName">
        </div>

        <div class="fieldcontain  required">
            <label for="email">
                Email
                <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" required="" value="" id="email">
        </div>

        <div class="fieldcontain  required">
            <label for="number">
                Number
                <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="number" required="" value="" id="number">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Wrap, your set of 4 elements i.e. `.fieldcontain` in a `div` with class `.row` like I've shown in the example.

Although, Grails provide a basic CSS for styling so the new projects can be bootstrapped fastly, but I recommend you to use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Comment: thanks for your reply. But it is resulting single field in each line as i added another image.

Comment: Sure I updated the answer. Please check it out. Like I mentioned in the answer, the  CSS of Grails is very basic. You will definitely start facing issues with CSS so I again recommend you to use some CSS library like Bootstrap. :-)

Comment: it's now showing 3 items in a line. I am accepting it as an answer. But I need 4 man.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Can you please further paste your new code

Comment: @SumonBappi I've updated the CSS and HTML markup. Please have a look. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<style>
#fieldlabel {display:block;}
#fieldinput {display:block;}
</style>
...
<body>
<label id="fieldlabel"><input type="text" id="fieldinput"></label>
</body>
...
```